# Is there a way to distribute and auto-update a Safari extension for free?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I don't have a server to distribute a Safari extension I made or to deploy updates. Is there a free service I can use instead of putting it on a file sharing website and posting to reddit?

Comment: I use Dropbox to host both the packaged extension and the Update.plist file. Any similar service that allows making files public should work.

Comment: @canisbos I tried to use GitHub and later rawgit.com to hold the files, but it doesn't seem to work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Amazon S3.

Just upload the .plist file and link everything up to each other. For low traffic, you won't be charged anything. With a few hundreds of users, it doesn't cost me more than a few cents every month. Keep in mind that your users' browsers will query your .plist file every time they open, so the traffic may pile up that way.

I wrote a [detailed tutorial here](http://code.antrikshy.com/safari-extension-development-automatic-updates/).